# 'Unable to cast object of type' in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have following query using `DataTable` give error:
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'"

```
var specList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where (decimal)r["stdyear"] == 0 && (string)r["SPECLIZATION"] != null
                                select r["SPECLIZATION"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

SPECLIZATION may be:

- ENG
- *NULL*
- MATH

How can I solve this problem? Guide me.

Comment: Check your SPECLIZATION value for DBNull.Value, not for null

Answer (score 1):

for `r["SPECLIZATION"]` ,it can be null,but before you check it is null or not ,you convert it to string first, so the excetption throw：  Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

```
var specList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where r.Field<decimal>("stdyear") == 0 && r.Field<string?>("SPECLIZATION").HasValue
                select r.Field<string?>("SPECLIZATION").Value).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explicitly called out your use of the `Field` method and why it is better.

Answer (score 0):

This `(string)r["SPECLIZATION"] != null` is failing when trying to cast `DBNull` to a `string`, just do this instead:

```
r["SPECLIZATION"] != DBNull.Value
```

Answer (score -1):

just use .ToString() , it works fine :)

```
var specList = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        where r["stdyear"].ToString() == "0" && r["SPECLIZATION"].ToString() != ""
                        select r["SPECLIZATION"]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
= dt.AsEnumerable().where(r=> r.Field<decimal>("stdyear") == 0 && r.Field<string> "SPECLIZATION") !=NULL).select(s=> s.Field<string>("SPECLIZATION")).Distinct().ToList();
```